# Alsa mixer won't save setting

Tags: audio, alsa, settings

I have [UGREEN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N905VOY) usb audio interface.
MY pi 4 is recognize it but no sound is comnig out. I try both via VLC player and via youtube (the video won't even play)

I did the follow:
I wrote at terminal: `sudo alsamixer` then I press F6 and choose device 3: USB Audio Device.
after that I press esc and then type at terminal: `sudo alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store`
I then reboot my pi and back to terminal and typed again: `sudo alsamixer` and the setting are back to the default device.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS now uses Pulse Audio rather than ALSA raspberrypi.org/blog/new-raspberry-pi-os-release-december-2020